# Custom ListView adapters with dynamic textView creation within the listview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

My requirement goes like the following:

Create a custom listview which has a title and subtitle (static contents from xml), followed by a linear layout which contains textviews, that will be created on runtime/dynamic. The number of textviews to be created on runtime may vary between 1-10. Beneath the linear layout, there could be one image or a textview (but only one).

Edit: Also these dynamic textview may or may not contain compound drawables on runtime.

I have tried the custom adapter extending the baseadapter and could achieve the title and subtitle along with image and textview. But I am unable to create dynamic textviews and add them to the listview's current list item.

Please find a sample reference in the image, the red bordered line represents the dynamic textviews to be created.

[image: Sample Reference]

Code Below:

```
for(int i =0; i< jsonDetails.size(); i++) {
    mh.textview1 = new TextView(context);

    if(null != jsonDetails.get(i+"")) {
        mh.linearLayout.addView(mh.textview1);
        mh.textview1.setLayoutParams(mh.textViewLP);
        mh.textview1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        mh.textview1.setText("Test" + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against trying to add/remove some arbitrary number of textviews dynamically like this. The approach I would take would be to combine the text elements into one element and always have just one TextView in the layout of your list item.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i =0; i< jsonDetails.size(); i++) {
    if (null != jsonDetails.get(Integer.toString(i)) {
        builder.append("APPEND TEXT HERE");
    }
}
mh.textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: This is rite. But if there is a need to add a compoundDrawable dynamically then i guess we have to add textviews. Am sorry i forgot to mention that in the requirement.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use a `SpannableStringBuilder` and add some `ImageSpan`s between elements.

Comment: Oh wow! I didnt know such a thing existing. Thanks for letting me know. I will try it out and mark as best answer.

Comment: I tried doing the same as u suggested. While the text gets appended and set to a master textview, the spannable images dont seem to render.

Comment: Don't call `toString()` with `SpannableStringBuilder`, just pass the `SpannableStringBuilder` itself when calling `setText()`

Comment: Oh well.. Let me try that

Comment: This is my code piece. Am I wrong somewhere?

`code
lineItem = new SpannableStringBuilder();

tempImg = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
tempImg.setBounds(0, 0, tempImg.getIntrinsicWidth(), tempImg.getIntrinsicHeight());
tempSpan = new ImageSpan(tempImg, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
lineItem.setSpan(tempSpan, 0, lineItem.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

text.append(lineItem);
code`

This doesnt append any image on a loop.

Comment: lineItem doesn't have any text in it, so its length is zero, and the span length is also zero. I suspect that might be the problem.

Comment: So should i append a text and then remove it off once the textview is filled with data? Which is the best method in this scenario?

Comment: No, the span encompasses some text. The text needs to be there for the span to be there. Just add a space or something.

Comment: hey. I have done this stuff. It now works fine. But the text with icons arent being vertically centred. Everything is baseline aligned. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with creating a new stringbuilder object with ," " quote. And appended each string to the text view. Finally I got the output working as required when used with linear layout n stuffs. Thanks for ur help :)